# FREE RPG How to convert %SUBST to TIMESTAMP?

Tags: db2, rpgle

I need to move a Substring into a Timestamp Field. But if I compile it,  I get the Error Number

**RNF7416 - The types of operands on the right and left sides of the expression in the EVAL operation do not match.**

The Code:

```
MONITOR;
  TSTPFIELD = %SUBST(NEWDS:01:26);
ON-ERROR;
  TSTPFIELD =  %TIMESTAMP();
ENDMON;
```

Do someone know how to convert the %SUBST(NEWDS:01:26) to Timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should do

tstamp = %timestamp(%SUBST(NEWDS:01:26))

You need to cast it to timestamp